# Give decimal quantity to the class cart in php

Tags: php, decimal, shopping-cart

I am using [this cart class](https://github.com/seikan/Cart) on my page.

My problem is, that now with this class, i cant give a decimal quantity from a product to the cart.

If, the minimum quantity that i can order of a product is 15,78 m2, the program will add it to the cart, but the 15,78 quantity value will be "converted" to 1.

How can i modify the add function in the class for this? Now, the code is original, i didnt modify it.

```
public function add($id, $quantity = 1, $attributes = array())
{
    $quantity = (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $quantity)) ? $quantity : 1;
    $attributes = (is_array($attributes)) ? array_filter($attributes) : $attributes = array();
    $hash = md5(json_encode($attributes));

    if (count($this->items) >= $this->cartMaxItem && $this->cartMaxItem != 0) 
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (isset($this->items[$id]))
    {
        foreach ($this->items[$id] as $index => $item) 
        {
            if ($item['hash'] == $hash) 
            {
                $this->items[$id][$index]['quantity'] += $quantity;
                $this->items[$id][$index]['quantity'] = ($this->itemMaxQuantity < $this->items[$id][$index]['quantity'] && $this->itemMaxQuantity != 0) ? $this->itemMaxQuantity : $this->items[$id][$index]['quantity'];

                $this->write();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }

    $this->items[$id][] = array
    (
        'id'         => $id,
        'quantity'   => ($quantity > $this->itemMaxQuantity && $this->itemMaxQuantity != 0) ? $this->itemMaxQuantity : $quantity,
        'hash'       => $hash,
        'attributes' => $attributes,
    );

    $this->write();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `15,78` is not a number it is a comma delimited list. `15.75` is a number

Comment: But this line `$quantity = (preg_match('/^\d+$/', $quantity)) ? $quantity : 1;` will convert anything to an integer or `1` anyway

Comment: Yes thats the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I read the documentation correct, you add an item and a quantity to cart and add some further information if needed. This information can be your 15,78 m2. So the customer ordered 1x 15.78 m2 from something with an ID in your Store.

"cartMaxItem" and "itemMaxQuantity" are from data type int, so you can change this or you change your shop logic to sell not m^2 but cm^2 and refer to the amount of cm^2 the customer can buy.

Comment: I don't recommend to change "cartMaxItem" to something else.
Change your shop logic as I mentioned and pass the amount of m^2 as parameter to the item->add() method ad shown in [here](https://github.com/seikan/Cart#add-item).

Answer (score 0):

This line `(preg_match('/^\d+$/', $quantity)) ? $quantity : 1` is a ternary operator which matches the given quantity to a regex pattern which says "If the quantity given is any sequence of at least int number or more (i.e. `1 is true`, `432 is true`, `84835 is true`, `2 is true`, `2.78 is false`), then pass it as it is. If the quantity given doesn't match the regex pattern (i.e. `2.78 which is false`) then assign the value 1 to this variable".

In your case you can either create a regex pattern like `/^\d+\.\d+$/` which will accept all kinds of numbers, separated with a dot (i.e. `2.78 is true`, `22.78 is true`, `84728774.87923587 is true`), or you can minimize the regex pattern up to your desired decimals like this `/\d+\.\d{2,3}/` . This pattern accepts only `2 or 3 digits` after the dot which means that numbers like `2.78, 22.789 or 287398724.32 are accepted`, but numbers like `2.8 or 2.9084 are NOT accepted`. That's all for regex.

After fixing your regex pattern, you can always use a typecasting method on your result like `$this->items[$id][$index]['quantity'] += (float)$quantity;` to add it to your total.

Make sure, that your quantities are always treated as floats, even when you use integers. For example, quantity `1` must be `1.00` .

The reason I suggest this regex modification is because your function already uses regex. Otherwise you can play only with value's length, value greater than 0 and other validations.

Hope it helps!